# Thymeleaf : template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: spring, tomcat, thymeleaf

I have this code:

```
private static final String EMAIL_INLINEIMAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME = "templateemail.html";

@Bean
public TemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {
    templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(this.htmlTemplateResolver());
       )

    templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(this.messageSource);
    return templateEngine;
}

private static ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
    final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(0));
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateResolver.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_MODE);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}


public void sendEmail(String emailAddress, String title, String body, Locale local, String image) {
    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(isEmailServiceActivated)) {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper mailMsg = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
        try {
            mailMsg.setFrom(EMAIL_USERNAME);
            mailMsg.setTo(emailAddress);
            mailMsg.setSubject(title);

            // Prepare the evaluation context
            ctx.setLocale(local);
            ctx.setVariable("imageHeaderResourceName", HEADER_LOGO_IMAGE);
            ctx.setVariable("body", body);

            ctx.setVariable("imageResourceName", image);

            final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process(new ClassPathResource(EMAIL_INLINEIMAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME).getPath(), ctx);
            mailMsg.setText(htmlContent, true );

            mailMsg.addInline(HEADER_LOGO_IMAGE, new ClassPathResource(HEADER_LOGO_IMAGE ) , PNG_MIME);
            mailMsg.addInline(image, new ClassPathResource(image) , PNG_MIME);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }
}
```

I have templateemail.html file under /templates/ directory. when I launch the sending email method I have this exception :

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "templateemail.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I dont know if it's because the templateEngine can't find my file (I try even with tomcat absolute path and /bin directory but no way ) or I haven't configure the right Template Resolver. 
Thank you very much for your help. I

Comment: it's `/templates` not `/template`. so just move the email file to the right folder

Comment: thanks for your help, I have edit my question to correct the name of the directory that I have already : templates and not template

Comment: in your sendEmail-method try to replace this line `final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process(new ClassPathResource(EMAIL_INLINEIMAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME).getPath(), ctx);` by `final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process(EMAIL_INLINEIMAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME, ctx);`

Comment: Originally , I have the same code that yours but it doesn't work :(

Comment: have you tried to debug the code an see what path is actually resolved?

Comment: yes , it's "/templates/templateemail.html "

Comment: It work now by deleting ".html" in the name of template (the file has the html extension)

private static final String EMAIL_INLINEIMAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME = "templateemail"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It work now by deleting ".html" in the name of template (the file has the html extension)

```
private static final String EMAIL_INLINEIMAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME = "templateemail"
```

Answer (score 4):

Note the non-cross-platform behavior that can occure: on Windows the CamelCase.html template was resolved, but not on Ubuntu linux! There I had to rename it to camelcase.html, all chars in lower case

Comment: if I do it via MVN it works perfect but if I package in .JAR and execute via JAVA can't resolve views

Comment: @richardhell I have exactly same problem. I am doing the development in Intellij. Running using maven and/or Intellij is fine, until we managed to package it in a JAR an run it on server, then such error came.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue recently. My problem was that my template had references to other templates that started with `/`.

For example:

```
<html ... th:include="/internal/layout-normal :: page">   <-- failed

<html ... th:include="internal/layout-normal :: page">    <-- worked
```

Both variants worked without problems when I run the application from IntelliJ. However, when packaged and run via `java -jar` the first line failed.

Removing the `/` solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf picks up the html files from resources/templates path by using the name of html file.
Hence in this case just removing .html extension from the filename would work!